# How can i authentication for API in jmter

Tags: api, jmeter

I want test API by jmeter but API has autentication so how can i give username and password to jmeter. i tried with HTTP authetication manager. and getting response 404 issue

Answer (score 0):

If the API is protected by one of the following techniques:

- [Basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)
- [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager)
- [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol))

you can bypass all of them using [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager)

Resources:

- [Basic authentication (Login) in JMeter](https://prelrik.wordpress.com/2016/05/03/basic-authentication-login-in-jmeter/)
- [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter)

The error [404 means that the URL is not found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404) at the endpoint you're testing, in case of authentication failure I would rather expect [HTTP status code 401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401)